# Add extra file to database, path is wrong

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-errors

I am creating a website using Python Django and the main purpose of the website is to modify XML files. I have uploaded the files to the hosting server and when I try to perform the conversion, I need to add another file to the database record that was created. On my local server, the process works smoothly without any issues, but when I try to do it on the hosting server, I get an error message:

```
"SuspiciousFileOperation at /test/ Detected path traversal attempt in '/home/t/tkor470gma/converter/new_CUST.xml".
```

My `models.py` looks like this:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(verbose_name='Document (old structure with settings)',upload_to='documents/')
    document1 = models.FileField(verbose_name='Document (new structures without settings)',upload_to='documents/')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resdocument = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/',blank=True)
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

`forms.py`

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ['document','document1']
```

`views.py` - this form uploads files to the database

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    form = DocumentForm()
    pathresdoc = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        obj = Document.objects.filter(author_id=user).order_by('-id')
        if obj.count() >= 1:
            return HttpResponse('it is impossible to convert first <button>Pay</button>')
    else:
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = user
            form.save()
            create_file(request.user.id)
            respeople = instance.id
            add_file_to_database('/home/t/tkor470gma/converter/new_CUST.xml',respeople)
            pathresdoc = Document.objects.get(id=respeople).resdocument.path
else:
    form = DocumentForm()
return render(request, 'model_form.html', {'form': form,'pathresdoc': str(pathresdoc)})
```

This one adds the resulting file to the database:

```
def add_file_to_database(file_path,idtransaction):
    my_file = File(open(file_path, 'rb'))
    model_instance = Document.objects.get(id=idtransaction)
    model_instance.resdocument = my_file
    model_instance.save_base()
```

This one creates the file itself:

```
def create_file(request):
    obj = Document.objects.filter(author_id=request).order_by('-id')[0]
     converterfile(str(obj.document.path),str(obj.document1.path),r"/home/t/tkor470gma/converter/new_CUST.xml")
```

This calls the program which converts the files:

```
def converterfile(file1,file2,file3):

     call(['python',"/home/t/tkor470gma/converter/backend/New_file.py", file1, file2, file3], shell=True)
```

How can I resolve this issue? I have tried using both the relative and absolute path, but the same error keeps appearing.

```
SuspiciousFileOperation at /test/
Detected path traversal attempt in 
'/home/t/tkor470gma/converter/new_CUST.xml'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:     
https://sapxmlversionup.ru/test/
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: SuspiciousFileOperation
Exception Value:    
Detected path traversal attempt in 
'/home/t/tkor470gma/converter/new_CUST.xml'
Exception Location:/home/t/tkor470gma/.djangovenv/lib/python3.8/sit 
e-packages/django/core/files/utils.py, line 
18, in validate_file_name
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/t/tkor470gma/converter/public_html',
 '/home/t/tkor470gma/converter',
```

[image: Error photo]

This is my hosting `settings.py`

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

# Build paths inside the project like this: 
BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = 
Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'documents')
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['sapxmlversionup.ru']

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
# Application definition
SITE_ID = 1

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'MainConv',
    'users',

]


MIDDLEWARE = [
   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Converter.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND':'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

 WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Converter.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 
'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'tkor470gma',
        'USER': 'tkor470gma',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'pg2.sweb.ru',
        'PORT': '5432',
}
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

USE_L10N = True


DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ( "%d/%m/%Y", )
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ( "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", )


LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And this local settings:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
SITE_ID = 1

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'modeltranslation',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'MainConv',
    'users',

]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Converter.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Converter.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'tkor470gma',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

USE_L10N = True

MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'en'

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ( "%d/%m/%Y", )
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ( "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", )


LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Comment: Could you paste the full trace of the error. Is your local Dev in debug mode? How is your media folder configured in both setup?

Comment: @jlandercy i add error full trace and settings local/hosting

Comment: When editing, please take care to not overwrite edits by other users.

Comment: oh okey .. my bad

Comment: The file needs to be in path defined by `MEDIA_ROOT`, if you want to have files outside project directory you need to rewrite the storage to omit Django internal check. For example I stick all uploaded files in `projectName/public/uploads` or `projectName/media` directories.

Comment: @PatrykSzczepański I have this file in this directory but even if I make the path to it, I will get the same error. SuspiciousFileOperation at /test/
Detected path traversal attempt in '/home/t/tkor470gma/converter/public_html/documents/documents/new_CUST.xml'

Comment: I see the update that will help in some extent. Notice picture are very poor format to exchange textual data, never ever take as screenshot of logs or table or error, copy paste it and then format. You probably have the answer in the comment. Cheers

Comment: @jlandercy thank you waiting for the answer

Comment: @jlandercy Do we need to make any additions/changes/supplements for greater clarity?

Comment: Hey, how's it going on this ?